# Else clause in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I use the following lambda expression to iterate over PDF files.

```
public static void run(String arg) {

        Path rootDir = Paths.get(arg);
        PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.pdf");
        Files.walk(rootDir)
                .filter(matcher::matches)
                .forEach(Start::modify);
    }

    private static void modify(Path p) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
```

This part `.forEach(Start::modify);` executes the static method modify from the same class where the lambda expression is located. Is there a possibility to add something like `else` clause when no PDF file is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect the result after the `filter` operation into a list instance and then check the size before operating on it.

```
List<Path> resultSet = Files.walk(rootDir)
                            .filter(matcher::matches)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
if(resultSet.size() > 0){
    resultSet.forEach(Start::modify);
}else {
    // do something else   
}
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
if(Files.walk(rootDir).anyMatch(matcher::matches)) {
         Files.walk(rootDir)
              .filter(matcher::matches)
              .forEach(Start::modify);
}else {
        // do something else    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you could just do the obvious thing, which is collect the stream first.

```
List<File> files = Files.walk(rootDir)
            .filter(matcher::matches)
            .collect(toList());

if (files.isEmpty())
    doSomethingForEmpty();
else
    files.forEach(Start::modify);
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer since Aominè was first and his and your solution are almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

If an API gives you a `Stream`, but `Stream` isn't what you need, you can always convert it to an `Iterable` and use a simple for loop:

```
boolean fileModified = false;
for (Path path : (Iterable<Path>) Files.walk(rootDir)::iterator) {
    if (matcher.matches(path)) {
        Start.modify(path);
        fileModified = true;
    }
} 
if (!fileModified) {
     // do something
}
```

This iterates the files only once and doesn't require forming an intermediate collection.